# Написание запроса MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Таблица Messages имеет такую структуру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

from_login who_login - это логины пользователей. 
Пытаюсь написать запрос, который выдал бы все диалоги пользователя 123(например).
Написал два запроса, но они выдают диалоги с повторами.

```
SELECT who_login FROM Messages WHERE from_login = '123' GROUP BY who_login
SELECT from_login FROM Messages WHERE who_login = '123' GROUP BY from_login
```

Подскажите как написать правильный запрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не это?

```
SELECT who_login FROM Messages WHERE from_login = '123'
UNION
SELECT from_login FROM Messages WHERE who_login = '123'
```

Comment: Да, то что надо, не знал что есть такой оператор UNION

Comment: Тогда дам ссылку: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_union.html :-)

Comment: А почему данных оператор UNION не работает с DELETE. Хочу написать запрос для удаления этих же строк но ничего не выходит

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM Messages WHERE '123' in (from_login, who_login)
```

Comment: Мне нужны логины а не id в этом вся и проблема