# Составление запроса DELETE с UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

Этот вопрос будет немного связан с  [предыдущим.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550394/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-mysql/550401?noredirect=1#comment705823_550401)

Пытаюсь удалить из этой таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

данные спарсеные таким образом:

```
SELECT who_login FROM Messages WHERE from_login = '123'
UNION
SELECT from_login FROM Messages WHERE who_login = '123'
```

использую для удаления такой запрос:

```
DELETE FROM
  Messages
WHERE id IN (SELECT
               id
             FROM
               Messages
             WHERE
               from_login = '123' AND who_login='123456'
             UNION
             SELECT
               id
             FROM
               Messages
             WHERE from_login = '123456' AND who_login='123')
```

В результате ошибка. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что MySQL не поддерживает `DELETE` и `UPDATE` запросы с вложенными запросами, в которых участвует таблица, подвергаемая изменениям. Для выполнения такой операции придется составить JOIN-запрос `DELETЕ` на самообъединение таблицы

```
DELETE
  Messages
FROM
  Messages
JOIN
   (SELECT
      id
    FROM
      Messages
    WHERE
      from_login = '123' AND who_login='123456'
    UNION
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      Messages
    WHERE
      from_login = '123456' AND who_login='123' ) AS del
ON
  Messages.id = del.id
```

Comment: ну если углубиться то можно.....`DELETE FROM Messages WHERE id IN (
 SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id FROM Messages WHERE from_login = '123' AND who_login='123456'
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM Messages WHERE from_login = '123456' AND who_login='123'
 ) AS p
)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хм... что-то даже никогда в голову такой вариант не приходил. Действительно можно так обойти, спасибо за вариант.

Comment: В любом случае ваш запрос несколько натуральнее выглядит, а не как хакерство)

Answer (score 2):

Как написал **@cheops** в ответе: MySQL не поддерживает DELETE и UPDATE запросы с вложенными запросами, в которых участвует таблица, подвергаемая изменениям.

Однако вы можете вложить выборку с `id` в другую выборку и дать некий псевдоним внутреннему подзапросу. Выглядит как хак, но рабочий

```
DELETE FROM `Messages` WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id FROM `Messages` WHERE from_login = '123' AND who_login='123456'
        UNION
        SELECT id FROM `Messages` WHERE from_login = '123456' AND who_login='123'
    ) AS m
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы очень сильно усложнили себе задачу. Из первоначального запроса видно, что вы хотите удалить записи у которых один из двух логинов равен 123, а второй 123456. Значит никаких id получать не надо, подзапрос не нужен. Просто задаем условия для отбора удаляемых записей:

```
DELETE FROM Messages
 WHERE (from_login = '123' AND who_login='123456')
    OR (who_login = '123'  AND from_login='123456')
```